# React Native Expo Application Stuck on Loading

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

I have developed a mobile app with React Native and Expo. I built the app using `eas build --profile development --platform android` and later said yes to the prompt to install the app on my Emulator. When I open the app, it gets stuck on the loading screen but it is working fine when testing using the expo client on the emulator.

I tried uninstalling the app and building again but that did not help.